# VS 2010 Test Runner error "The agent process was stopped while the test was running."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a number of unit tests. When I run multiple tests at one time using test lists, I sometimes reveive the following error for one or more of the tests:

> The agent process was stopped while
> the test was running.

It is never the same test failing, and if I try to run the test again, it succeeds.

I found this [bug report on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/482790/test-agent-stability-problems), which seems to be the same problem, but it does not offer a solution.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour ? How I can avoid it ?

## Edit

I am still experiencing this bug, and so is many of my colleagues on the same software/hardware setup. I have evaluated the answers so far, but they don't resolve the problem. I am starting a bounty for a solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I'm digging into it but no solution so far

Comment: Any news on this? Same problem here...

Comment: @Peter, see my comment below accepted answer. That was my solution, but I don't know if your problem is similar.

Comment: I had the same behaviour with an uncaught exception. The exception was visible for me as I run Visual Studio on the build server and got an Assert-Window. Because of the assert window the test couldn't go on.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've just experienced the similar problem: some tests fail and they are different in different test runs. I don't know exactly the reason why it happens, but it began to occur when I added a finalizer to one of my classes. When I disable the finalizer - the problem disappears. When I turn the finalizer on - the problem comes back.

Right now I don't know how to overcome this.

Comment: THANKS - this answer lead me to the solution. I only have a finalizer on a couple of types, and sure enough, removing them also removed the problem. Upon further investigation, I discovered a subtle bug in one finalizer, which occured only when an exception was thrown in the constructor, and the finalizer tries to finalize an object that is not fully constructed. Conclusion: If an exception occurs in a finalizer on a type, and that finalizer runs before all the tests has finished, Visual Studio will give the error I was facing; without any further explanation, and on random tests.

Comment: I have no finalizers/destructors in my code ...   ~MyClass()  and get the same error. Running tests with Resharper are all green

Comment: The problem with uncaught exceptions in finalizers is a special case of uncaught exceptions in background tasks which can be started or scheduled (perhaps implicitly) by some test and can continue executing even if  the test has been completed.

Comment: Same as Peter, Resharper test runner gives me all green. VS 2010 test runner fails on class with destructor.

Comment: Had the same problem in a third-party project, putting a null check in the `Dispose` (which was called by `Finalize`) method solved that problem for me.

Comment: I had accidentally coded an infinite recursive loop in my Dispose() method, which also caused this.

Comment: @JeanHominal, was it another disposable resource that was `null` and you were trying to call `Dispose` on it? I'm experiencing this same issue when unit testing NAudio using the `WaveIn/OutEvent` classes.

Comment: I got this error when I managed to write a method that called another method, which called the first one and so on.. Neither of these methods had anything to do with `Finalize` nor `Dispose`.

Comment: For future readers... maybe use the Windows **Event Viewer** to look for an **Error** log entry at the time the test failed, as per what worked for me in my answer down below.

Answer (score 89):

This message is caused by an **exception on a thread different from the executing test thread**. All answers so far boil down to this simple explanation. It is a known bug in Visual Studio not to display any sensible information in that case.

Visual Studio’s test runner totally chokes if a thread other than the executing test thread throws an exception: It gets swallowed and there’s no output, no chance to intercept and debug and no nothing except a burned-down smoldering mess that was supposed to be your unit test.

Comment: The same thing happened for me too - my test was spawning a separate thread, which was getting an exception.  Catching the exception inside the thread at least allows me to print it and know what's happening.  However be careful not to put Assert.Fail() in the thread's catch block - that raises a separate exception which puts you right back where you started.

Comment: same thing for me, except a stack overflow, which are so much harder to track down in C# compared to java...

Comment: Indeed, I noticed this happened when I started using Thread objects and calling Abort() to stop them.

Comment: This also happens when an `async void` method that is called during the test throws an exception

Comment: Note that the trx might contain the error information, you can see it either by opening it in a text editor, or in Visual Studio and clicking the *Test run error* hyperlink in the *Test Results* window.

Answer (score 17):

I was having this problem, and it turned out to be a problem in my code which the Test Framework wasn't catching properly. A little accidental refactoring had left me with this code:

```
public void GetThingy()
{
    this.GetThingy();
}
```

This is of course an infinite recursion, and caused a StackOverflowException (I guess). What this caused was the dreaded: "The agent process was stopped while the test was running."

A quick code inspection showed me the problem, and my tests are now running fine. Hope this helps - might be worth inspecting the code looking for issues, or maybe extracting a bit into a console app and checking it works properly there.

Comment: This is not the issue (I know because it is different tests that fail each time), but thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: +1 as this is one of many valid answers for this issue. an SO exception in a sstatic method on one of my classes caused this issue.

Comment: +1, I've seen this too. Debugging the test (in VS 11) finds the problem pretty quickly.

Comment: Agree with Jeremy. If you debug the unit tests then it should stop where the exception is thrown. However if you just run the unit tests they'll all come up with green lights. Very bizarre.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to find the source of my problem by looking in the test result file (/TestResults/*.trx)  It provided the full details of the exception that occurred in the background thread, and once I resolved that exception the "agent processed stopped..." error went away.

In my case I was unintentionally launching the GUI in my unit test, which eventually caused a System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException to be thrown.

So my .trx file contained:

```
   <RunInfo computerName="DT-1202" outcome="Error" timestamp="2013-07-29T13:52:11.2647907-04:00">
    <Text>One of the background threads threw exception: 
System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException: An error occurred invoking the method.  The destination thread no longer exists.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
...
</Text>
  </RunInfo>
```

This didn't provide any information on what test caused the error, but it did show me where the exception was, which was very useful.

Answer (score 5):

This message is typically generated when the test process crashes and can happen when there is an unhandled exception on a background thread, a stack overflow occurs, or an explicit call to `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` or `Environment.Exit`. Another possible cause is an access violation in unmanaged code.

Something no one has mentioned is that there may be additional information in the event log. Usually you will not get much information on why the test crashed in the results, however in the event of an unhandled exception on a background thread, then the test framework writes details to the Application event log with source VSTTExecution. If there is no information written to the event log then it is likely one of the other causes listed above.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same Problem and solved it while Removing

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

So i am pretty sure, that this error occurs while your test or method under test, is causing the executing process to terminate.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the solution was resolved by checking the **Output Window**.

> 'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed
>   (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\TestResults\bdewey_XXXXXX072
>   2011-01-11
>   17_00_40\Out\MyCode.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. E, 9024, 9,
>   2011/01/11, 17:00:46.827,
>   XXXXX072\QTAgent32.exe, Unhandled
>   Exception Caught, reporting through
>   Watson:  [Exception message]

In my case I had a FileSystemWatcher that was throwing an error on a seperate thread.

Comment: how did you solve it? I'm using some sample code from M$ that wraps the FileSystemWatcher in a service and creates a WF workflow around that.  I'm getting lots of these...

Comment: In my case, two tests failed. When I went to the **Output** pane and chose **Tests**, it mentioned "One of the background threads threw exception"... in fact, 9 NullReferenceExceptions were waiting for me with stack traces. Thanks, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting the question.  I just ran into this problem and figured out a cause that you may be running into.

> An asynchronous exception may have
>   occurred

During my test setup, I create an object that queues a worker thread in the thread pool.  If I run through debugging fast enough my code passes.

If the worker thread kicks off and has an error BEFORE the test setup completes, then I get a result of Aborted with no reasoning.

If the worker thread kicks off and has an error AFTER the test has begun, then I get a result of : Error - The agent process was stopped while the test was running.

Important to note: this is a component that I use throughout several of my tests.  If the test framework encounters too many of these errors it aborts the rest of the tests.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am aware that asynchronous exceptions might cause something similar to what I am seeing, but I am almost certain that this is not the case. Code is for a web app, and we don't do anything asynchronously. Also, it seems that which test that fails is random.

Answer (score 2):

I added try/catch blocks to the descructor  ~ClassName(){}  that were defined in any class involved in my tests. This fixed the problem for me.

```
~MyClass()
{
    try
    {
        // Some Code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the exception so it's not totally hidden
        // Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For finding out where the exception was thrown click on the hyperlink "Test Run Error" next to the exclamation icon in the Test Results window. A window with the stack trace is opened.

This helps a lot to track down the error!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by a finalizer for an unmanaged resource (a file writer that was not getting disposed properly for some reason).

After wrapping the finalizer code in a try-catch that swallows the exception, the problem disappeared. I don't recommend swallowing exceptions like that, so it would obviously be wise to find out why the exception is occurring in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happening on the odd occasion, and the culprit almost always turns out to be threading.

Strangely enough all the tests would work fine on the development machines, then randomly fail on the build servers.

On closer inspection it turned out that although the tests were being listed as passed on the dev boxes, there were exceptions being thrown. The exceptions were being thrown on a seperate thread which didn't get picked up as an error.

The exception details were being logged against the test trace, so we were able to identify which code/tests needed to be modified.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some unit-tests for a WCF-service. This WCF service was starting up 2 timers.
Those timers caused side effects.
 --> I disable these timers by default and everything is fine!

BTW: I use [WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/) to fake the WCF service, so I have "real" unit tests around my WCF service

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by a Finalizer for me as well.
The Finalizer was actaully calling some DB code which wasn't mocked out. Took me a while to find it as it wasn't a class I wrote and the reference to it was burred quite a few classes deep.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar problem where a test is failing in TestInitialize and is also running code from a ddl from another of my projects. I get the error message as described above and if I try to debug the test, the test is just aborted without any exception details.

I suspect that the problem may be that the dlls from my other project are from a Visual Studio 2012 project and I am running my tests in a VS2010 project, and/or possibly that the UnitTestFramwork dll versions from the 2 projects are mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be triggered by an Exception or Stackoverflow in Constructor of a TestClass.

Answer (score 0):

As this error can have many different causes, I'd like to add another one for completeness of this thread.

If *all* your tests are aborting as described by the OP, the cause might be a wrong project configuration. In my case the target framework was set to .NET Framework 3.5. Setting it to a higher version through the project properties page (tab *Application*) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine what was causing my issue by looking in the **Windows Logs** > **Application** log entries within the **Windows Event Viewer**. Look for entries at the time the test bombed-out. I had an **Error** entry similar to below:

```
QTAgent32_40.exe, PID 10432, Thread 2) AgentProcess:CurrentDomain_UnhandledException: IsTerminating : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at XXX.YYY.ZZZ.cs:line 660
   at XXX.YYY.AAA.Finalize() in C:\JenkinsSlave\workspace\XXX.YYY.AAA.cs:line 180
```

It was indeed a null reference exception within a method called from a class finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone happening upon this old question and wondering what's being thrown from their thread(s), here's a tip. Using Task.Run (as opposed to, say, Thread.Start) will report child thread exceptions much more reliably. In short, instead of this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(FunctionThatThrows);
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

Do this:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => FunctionThatThrows());
t.Wait();
```

And your error logs should be much more useful.