# Most reliable approach to unit testing used as part of build acceptance where the class contains multiple threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, moq, vs-unit-testing-framework

Consider this unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void QueueManager_OnNextItem()
    {
        bool called = false;
        var queue = new QueueManager<int>(
                        new Moq.Mock<ILogger>().Object, 
                        new Moq.Mock<IItemQueueManagerPerformanceTracker>().Object);

        queue.OnNextItem += i => { called = true; };

        queue.Add(1);
        queue.Start();

        //need to RELIABLY wait here

        Assert.IsTrue(called);
    }
```

`QueueManager` has a worker thread running internally (`Start()` kicks it off) which dequeues an item and calls `OnNextItem`.

As this test stands it will always **always** fail, as the `Assert...` is called before there is a context switch, to allow `called = true` to be executed.

I did place a `Thread.Sleep(blah)` prior to the `Assert...`.

This **does** work when the test is run in isolation.

However, run it will the other load of unit tests and I found I was being presented with the good old...

> the agent process was stopped while the test was running

...which has no immediate resolution [Unit Testing - The agent process was stopped while the test was running.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556702/unit-testing-the-agent-process-was-stopped-while-the-test-was-running) and leaves you exposed to [VS 2010 Test Runner error “The agent process was stopped while the test was running.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810012/vs-2010-test-runner-error-the-agent-process-was-stopped-while-the-test-was-runni)

So, in light of that...what approach can I use to ensure that I test that my event is being fired **AND** it is reliable so as not to bork my build process?

TIA

Comment: I was getting this message, and it turned out to be an exception being thrown on a thread created by ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkitem. Setting a breakpoint (and appropriate logging) led me to finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make the `OnNextItem` responsible for unblocking:

```
// Setup as before
object monitor = new object();
queue.OnNextItem += i => { lock(monitor) { Monitor.Pulse(monitor); }};

lock (monitor)
{
    queue.Add(1);
    queue.Start();
    Assert.IsTrue(Monitor.Wait(monitor, 1000));
}
```

That will wait up to one second for `OnNextItem` to be called, and fail if the wait times out.

Comment: Ta very much :)

However, the whole issue regarding testing multi threaded code will only get more obvious, especially with more use of the TPL which has it's own gotchas and caveats to correct usage.