# "The agent process was stopped while the test was running" on Automated Unit Tests in TFS 2010 CI Build

Tags: msbuild, mstest, tfsbuild

I try to integrate/automate some unit tests with our TFS 2010 CI build process and got this strange error message when the test failed.

After spending some time trying to figure out what the root cause was I've simplified the code down to just a few lines:

if I do something like

```
Book b = new Book { ID = 1, Name = "test book" };
Category c = new Category { ID = 1, Name = "test category" };

Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
```

then everything is fine. But if I do:

```
Book b = new Book { ID = 1, Name = "test book" };
Category c = new Category { ID = 1, Name = "test category" };

b.Category = c;

Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
```

The unit test will fail with the "The agent process was stopped while the test was running" message.

Both versions work fine if I run the test in isolation on my local machine.

I look at the Event Viewer on my build server and see this:

```
Faulting application name: QTAgent32.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba20efb
Faulting module name: System.Data.Entity.ni.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1e2fd
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0029ffae
Faulting process id: 0x484
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd74e84f30a93b
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.Entity\7aa839fb16503243d6ae454ab334bcf4\System.Data.Entity.ni.dll
Report Id: 8d4222b0-e0db-11e1-8dbe-005056a3481b
```

Anyone here seen this strange behavior before?

EDIT: I'm using EF 4.0, database-first model so all the entity classes were created by using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS 2010 Test Runner error "The agent process was stopped while the test was running."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810012/vs-2010-test-runner-error-the-agent-process-was-stopped-while-the-test-was-runn)